# Retrieve image URL using a Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am in the process of making a bookmarklet for my website.

When clicked i need it to do either one of two things.

1. Retreive all images that are on the page then show them in the bookmarklet.

or

1. Once opened the next image that is clicked on on the page is loaded into the bookmarklet.

I think the part that i am struggling with is that i cant get the bookmarklet to interact with the page at all, it's almost as if it doesn't know the page is there if that makes sense?

P.s i am using google chrome to test this and i am loading it as a extension.

Comment: a bookmarklet is a bookmark that executes a javascript snippet on the page... how are you trying to load something "into" the bookmarklet?

Comment: Thats what i am struggling with. I have used bookmarklets before that when you open them you it retrieves all the images on the page you was on then you can select which one to upload to your profile.